# Texture baking: some part of my object is always black after baking

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm a newbie in blender, currently I'm using blender 2.8 to make a character.
I followed this tutorial on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYBPXTful2g

The problem is that when I performed Bake as the tut, my character hair and helmet are always black. You can prefer the image. Before this, I separated the helmet and hair to other object and merged them with the body later so I suspect this may be the reason but I don't know how to fix it.

Could you help me with this?

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no Blender Render engine in 2.8. To use Cycles is a bit different. Try to search bake with Cycles.

Comment: Hi FFeller, thanks for your reply. But the images are the output of Bake using Cycles. I changed the Render Engine to Cycles and under Bake tab I set Bake Type to Ambient Occlusion, after that I hit Bake button and get that result.

Comment: Hi. I probably found your problem. The black part's face normals pointing inside. You have to recalculate them to outside. Just select all of them then click on Mesh>Normals>Recalculate outside. But what I talked about before to use the cycles baking normally you have to use the Shader Editor. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Jb3BRn_-DA

Comment: Hi FFeller, I followed your instruction and the issue is fixed, thank you very much for your quick response. And also thank you about the video, I'm getting the idea of the flow to use the cycles baking.